# Understanding the fundamental theorem of calculus via squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I was just taught "integration is the opposite of differentation, this will give the area"

While I can integrate, I am not sure why it works and the "anti derivate" magically is the area. I really need some help getting this idea in my head. I am using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus for reference.

If we want A(x), I am not sure how adding an extra red section helps. I *think* I understand the red area is defined as approximateley A(x)-A(x-h), which equals f(x)h.

Then I have read, this is between

hf(x)< RED AREA < f(x+h).

I then see we divide by h, and are left with the defintion of differentation when h>>0.

However I have 2 questions'
1) Surely we are not concerned with the red area, we want the blue area
2) When we take the limit as h>>0 this leaves an infitesimal slice (I understand that integration is the summation of an infinate amount of infiniately small sliced) but the concept of adding +h to the area (thus creating a red area) only to remove it doesn't seem to have any effect on the blue area.

Thanks a lot for your help. Hopefully its something easy I missed, and I can get there!

Comment: General remark: Wikipedia is a great (re)source, but if you're studying a topic from scratch, I would advise to look for material that deals with the topic in more detail; that could be another website but perhaps even better: a decent old school book :-). But thumbs up for trying to study a new topic on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I can do integration, just not sure why I should be doing integration and how its the area.I just dont follow the idea of x+h and how it helps us get the blue area.

Comment: "I was just taught [that] integration is the opposite of differentation". Who taught you this?? Personally, I think that this not good, pedagogically.  It has suddenly made you think that the fundamental theorem of calculus should be easy to see.

Comment: You don't want the blue area $A(x)$ directly, you want its *derivative* with respect to $x$. (Since if you can show that $A'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, then it follows that you can find $A(x)$ by finding an antiderivative of $f(x)$.) So you must see how much $A(x)$ *changes* if you change $x$ a little. That change is the red area.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that if I differentiate A(x), I will get f(x), but may I ask why you want to differentiate A to get the area, when A is the area? What is the logic or intuition in this?

Comment: You're not "differentiating $A$ to get the area." You can differentiate $A$ to get $f$, but usually you're going the other way around, and you want to get $A$ when you already know $f$. The fundamental theorem of calculus just tells you that $A$ is some function whose derivative is $f$, so if you know $f$, you know where to look to find possible $A$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the feeling that a part of your confusion comes from the fact that you're reading a paragraph of the Wikipedia-page with an expectation that's different from its goal. They don't *define* the integral in that paragraph.

> 2) When we take the limit as h>>0 this leaves an infitesimal slice (I understand that integration is the summation of an infinate amount of infiniately small sliced) but the concept of adding +h to the area (thus creating a red area) only to remove it doesn't seem to have any effect on the blue area.

You are right: you don't *need* the red part to understand what the integral does, where it comes from, how it is defined. As you say: you divide the interval into subintervals and you build rectangles whose length you let go to 0. Adding the areas of the rectangles gives an approximation of the area under the curve and we get (or: *define*!) the *real area* by taking the limit of $h \to 0$ (I'm omitting details here). This is done in many books, websites and partly also in the Wikipedia article.

However, you're referring to the picture and the reasoning in the paragraph [Geometrical meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Geometric_meaning) and there, they are trying to explain what the relation is between actually calculating this area and the concept of derivatives and anti-derivatives. More precisely: it gives you the relation between $f$ and the *area function* $A$, and they're connected as one being the derivative of the other one.

> Thanks, I can see that if I differentiate A(x), I will get f(x), but may I ask why you want to differentiate A to get the area, when A is the area? What is the logic or intuition in this?

So what they achieved in that paragraph is showing that you can obtain a formula for the area under the graph of $f$, if you can find a function $A$ that satisfies $A'(x) = f(x)$, what we call an **anti-derivative** (or **primitive function**) of $f$. Note that you don't necessarily "discover" this relation if you only define the integral as the limit of a sum of areas of rectangles.

Comment: Thank you very much @StackTD

Comment: You're welcome! @MathsWiz